# About Username and Pasword Encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I have a table in database with this structure:

```
+----------+----------+-----+-------+---------+--------------+
| Username | Password | Age | email | Address | Phone Number |
+----------+----------+-----+-------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to store this table's data  in the data base so that i can fetch it later for further use.

I want to store the password in the database in the encrypted form so that nobody can see the password.

How can i do this ?

Example :

```
+-------+------------+
| name  |   password |
+-------+------------+
|abc    |  ******    |
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Use any good hashing algorithm, bcrypt or something similar. They should not be encrypted, but really hashed.

Comment: can you suggest some plzz @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: he did suggest bcrypt

Comment: What no ? He did suggest bcrypt man what else are you expecting ?

Comment: I want exact program actually

Comment: "I want exact program actually..." if you want teh codez, you've come to the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any hashing library, like bcrypt or pyblake2 (not hashlib, not meant for this task).

Be aware that this is one way only, once the string is hashed, you cannot get the original password,  that's were security lies. You then compare the stored hash against the hash of the password when needed.

Also consider salting the hash, and you can store the salt in the db as well.